# Authenticate Chrome's remoting( Remote Desktop ) using third party

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, chrome-remote-desktop

If yes then how can we achieve this? By third party I mean using customized authentication service other than google accounts. Platform: Browser app & android

My question is based on fact that in remoting code repository ( https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/remoting/ ) there is commit (Revision 190024) which says adding "Third Party authentication protocol".Please correct if I misunderstood this commit intent. Details below :

Revision 190024 - (view) (annotate) - [select for diffs]
Modified Sat Mar 23 16:27:52 2013 UTC (4 years, 1 month ago) by rmsousa@chromium.org
File length: 2827 byte(s)
Diff to previous 150225

I tried building Chrome RDP using instruction mentioned in following links but to my bad I didn't find any step suggesting third party authentication.

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/184niJVxEfBoYqOrL_BLIHR8PNTbvCnGcFy3Rwb7NbPU/edit
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkcr/docs/old_chromoting_build_instructions.md
```

As its open sourced there is no point to force users to users certain type of authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jamie Walch from chromium.org ,my query was resolved, Posting here for other's use.

- Third Party authentication could be done in principle but the party has to develop &  deploy it's own back-end services like  directory server , TURN service etc.By Google Oauth ,all these respective service APIs are provided by google itself.
- Bigger concern related to this is sooner these chrome apps are going to deprecated hence the APIs providing different service will be of no use. Please refer to this [blog](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html) items